# Convert UnsafeMutablePointer<Int16> to UInt8

Tags: swift, unsafemutablepointer

I am trying to convert this `Int16` mutable pointer to `UInt8` to be written on a OutputStream. I tried to use the function `.withMemoryRebound` but I don't know how to do it correctly. I would like to do it using this function, I tried once but no success. I am able to get something working with the code below, but I don't think it is correct.

```
unwrappedOutputStream.open()

let buffer: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int16> = avAudioPCMBuffer.int16ChannelData![0]
let size = MemoryLayout<UInt8>.size

let bound: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt16> = UnsafeMutablePointer.allocate(capacity: 1)
bound.pointee = UInt16(bitPattern: buffer.pointee)

let bytePointer: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8> = UnsafeMutablePointer.allocate(capacity: 1)

bytePointer.pointee = UInt8(bound.pointee >> 0x8)
unwrappedOutputStream.write(bytePointer, maxLength: size)

bytePointer.pointee = UInt8(bound.pointee & 0xff)
unwrappedOutputStream.write(bytePointer, maxLength: size)

bound.deallocate(capacity: 1)
bytePointer.deallocate(capacity: 1)

unwrappedOutputStream.close()
```

I am currently using Swift 4, is there anything I can do?
Thank you and I appreciate your patience.

Comment: Does `flushData.buffer` point to the data that you want to write? Does it point to a single Int16 value or to an array of values? Do you want to write the values in host byte order or as bigendian?

Comment: @MartinR I think it's pointing to the first array of the `int16ChannelData` array used on `AVAudioPCMBuffer`. Directly translate it to `avAudioPCMBuffer.int16ChannelData![0]`.

Comment: Code updated :)

Comment: Any feedback on the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Casting an `Unsafe(Mutable)Pointer<Int16>` to `UnsafePointer<Int8>`
would simply be:

```
let buffer: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int16> = ...
let count: Int = ... // # of Int16 values

let result = buffer.withMemoryRebound(to: UInt8.self, capacity: 2 * count) {
    outputStream.write($0, maxLength: 2 * count)
}
```